# Deriving expression for expected offspring in branching process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am looking at branching processes in [Dobrow 2016](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/~giacomo/Softwares/R/Dobrow%20-%20Stochastic%20with%20R/ch4.pdf) (p. 160), where the author states that the "mean of the offspring distribution" is $\mu =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k a_k$.  I want to know why the following equation holds:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E} \Big( \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \Big) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \Big( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k a_k \Big).$$

How is this result obtained?

Answer (score 2):

The paper specifies that $X_1,X_2,X_3,... \sim \text{IID Offspring}$ are values from the offspring distribution.  It also gives the mean of the offspring distribution as:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \mu = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k a_k.$$

Hence, using the linearity of the expectation operator, you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{E} \Big( \sum_{i=1}^k  X_i \Big) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb{E}(X_i) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^k \mu \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \mu \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \Big( \sum_{k=0}^\infty k a_k \Big). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$